# i'm using the loop + jQuery below to load in the next set of pages but it's showing only 2 pages but i have 20 post and i'm showing 4 post perpage

Tags: ajax, wordpress, jquery-pagination

```
      <?php $new_query = new WP_Query();
       $new_query->query('showposts=4'.'&paged='.$paged);?>
       <?php while ($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post(); ?>
       <li>
       <?php the_title();?>
       </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <div id="pagination">
    <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); } else { ?>
    <div class="alignleft">
      <?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?>
    </div>
    <div class="alignright">
      <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?>
    </div>
     <?php 
     } ?>
     </div>
```

it's working but only showing 2 pages but i have 20 posts and i'm showing 4 posts per page

```
  <script>
   jQuery(function($) {
    $('ul.govtjobs').on('click', '#pagination a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('ul.govtjobs').fadeOut(100, function(){
        $(this).load(link + ' ul.govtjobs', function() {
            $(this).fadeIn(100);
        });
    });
    });
   });
   </script>
```

and i'm using this script for go to next page

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'paged' => $paged,
    );
$new_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

It is recommended to use `posts_per_page`.